# high/low from midnight to midnight

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I wish to plot the previous days high/low from 0:00 to 0:00 and plot it on the current day. I am finding this a challenge because I dont want to use the standard daily high/low because that is the brokers hours and dont match the high/low that I need when I use UTC-4 New York time.

I can get the high/low for a time range too but not specifically the previous day

I attempted the following code but the plotted high/low repaints over the current day and not show a straight line of the previous day

```
//@version=5
indicator("Previous Day High and Low 0:00 to 23:55", overlay=true)

// Define the start and end times
startHour = 0
endHour = 23
endMinute = 55

// Determine if the current bar falls within our defined time range
isWithinTimeRange(time) =>
    t = timestamp("UTC", year, month, dayofmonth, hour, minute)
    start_time = timestamp("UTC", year[1], month[1], dayofmonth[1], startHour, 0)
    end_time = timestamp("UTC", year[1], month[1], endHour, endMinute)
    t[1] >= start_time and t[1] <= end_time

// Calculate the high and low for the defined period
var float prevHigh = na
var float prevLow = na

if (isWithinTimeRange(time))
    prevHigh := na(prevHigh) ? high : math.max(prevHigh, high)
    prevLow := na(prevLow) ? low : math.min(prevLow, low)

plot(bar_index[1] == bar_index ? na : prevHigh, title="Previous Day High 0:00 to 23:55", color=color.green, linewidth=2)
plot(bar_index[1] == bar_index ? na : prevLow, title="Previous Day Low 0:00 to 23:55", color=color.red, linewidth=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dayofweek()` to detect a new day in a desired timezone.

```
dayofweek(time, timezone) → series int
```

Just pass the `timezone` and then compare its current value with its previous value.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

session_timezone = "GMT-4"

is_new_day_tf = timeframe.change("D")  // This will use exchange's timezone

today_adjusted = dayofweek(time, session_timezone)
is_new_day = today_adjusted != today_adjusted[1]

plotshape(is_new_day)
bgcolor(is_new_day_tf ? color.new(color.green, 85) : na)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**approach recommended by vitruvius...**

This will calculated the daily `high` & `low` and will copy those values then reset on a daily bases.

```
var high_today = float(high)
var low_today  = float(low)

var high_yesterday = float(na)
var low_yesterday  = float(na)

if ta.change(dayofweek(time, "America/New_York"))
    high_yesterday := high_today
    low_yesterday  := low_today
    high_today     := high
    low_today      := low
else
    high_today := math.max(high, high_today)
    low_today  := math.min(low , low_today)

plot(high_yesterday, "h")
plot(low_yesterday, "l")
```

This was complicated cause I needed to declare variables via `var` to be consistent.
And then I had to check when a new day starts, so I could copy the values and start fresh for today.

The line `ta.change(dayofweek(time, "America/New_York"))` does what vitruvius mention and you wants. It checks if a new day has started for NY timezone. You could change `America/New_York` into any timezone you want, like `UTC-4`.
Reference: [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC) and [RFC2822](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2822#section-3.3)